# How can I add more force to an object to be able to pass over a stair without adding speed to the force using rigidbody?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to set the speed to 500 at least to make the object roll and pass the small stair.
but I don't want it to roll that fast. Is there any other way to give the object som push ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rolling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NaviManager naviManager;
    public float speed;
    public string onCollisionState;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private bool isTouching = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (naviManager.crateOpenOnce)
        {
            if (isTouching)
            {
                Vector3 movement = new Vector3(1f, 0.0f, -1f);

                rb.AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                rb.velocity = rb.velocity * 0.95f * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Crate_0_0")
        {
            onCollisionState = "Touching !!!";

            isTouching = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I built with these two cubes a slope to help the object to roll out the problem is that the object can't roll over it climb it up because it doesn't have power. Setting the speed to 500 is not a solution. I don't want the object to roll so fast.

[image: The slope stair I created]

and this screenshot is of the rolling object. The rolling object has Rigidbody and Capsule Collider components.

[image: Object that roll]

I paused the game but if the game continues the object will not have enough power to climb over this small stair slope and will move out of the box from the side. I want it to climb the slope and to roll out from the box opening.

Comment: the pivot of your ball does not seem quite right in the picture. I would have that in the centre. I would try [AddForceAtPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html) in the direction of the slope when the ball is in touch with the slope. At position to be sure the force is applied in the center to avoid momentum generation (roll speed).

Comment: Other thing you can try out is the [WheelCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelCollider.html). This would make the ball move as a wheel  applying rotation to the ball so that it will move with physics according to the friction with the floor (as a vehicle wheel). That way you would be able to climb slopes up without speed manipulation.